# setOnItemClickListener not working inspite of removing focus on every view

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

Yes i know this has been asked many times. I tried every solution provided but ain't working for me. So i am again asking the same question again.

This is my layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/view_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="3dp">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/calcName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textColor="#FF000000" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/nextImg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end|right"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/strImg"
        android:src="@drawable/next" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see i have made every view loose focus even the root view does it.

Then here is my adapter class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.everythingrf.android.rfcalculators.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


    public class CommonListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<String> mDataObjects;
        private int layout;

        public CommonListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            mContext = context;
            layout = resource;
            mDataObjects = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

                holder.calcName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.calcName);
                holder.nextImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nextImg);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.calcName.setFocusable(false);
            holder.nextImg.setFocusable(false);

            holder.calcName.setText(mDataObjects.get(position));


            return convertView;
        }

        public static class ViewHolder{
            TextView calcName;
            ImageView nextImg;
        }
    }
```

Even tried with the adapter

Here is my main class which calls onItemClickListener

```
myCalcList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Log.e("Main","item click");
        String selectedCalc = commonList.get(pos);
        openSelectedCalc(selectedCalc);
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: @bhargav nope, data is loaded fine...when i click it nothing happens..Log does not print, even attached debugger inside the method does not get called

Comment: you can use recycleView instead of listView, there are a lot of benefits using recycleView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please just remove android:clickable="true" from row layout,this will work.

As each row is consuming the event which prevent the listview to execute the onItemClick.

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending yout Main from ListActivity in your onCreate method you have to put something like

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Look I have a example of a custom ListView in my GitHub https://github.com/alvaroroyo/ListViewCustom/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/aroyo/listaliada